# How to consume existing WCF service in Sharepoint 2010 webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

How to consume existing WCF service deployed on IIS7 in Sharepoint 2010 webpart. This WCF service is provided by another client so I cannot make any changes to it.

Thanks

Comment: Add a service reference! Seriously, please only ask questions when you have a specific issue. Read the [faq], [ask] and http://whathaveyoutried.com pages.